# Maven Eclipse plugin doesn't regard Maven failsave plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, classpath, maven-plugin

I'm just using Maven to build my project and also my eclipse project settings. The eclipse:eclipse target generates the .classpath file for eclipse regarding the dependencies and other project settings like source directory, test source directory and so on. Now I added the Maven failsafe plugin and defined a `<testSourceDirectory>/test/integration</testSourceDirectory>` beside my normal (junit) test directory.

- test/unit -> contains my junit test cases which are executes in maven "test" phase
- test/integration -> contains my integration (maybe also junit) test cases, executed in maven phase "integration-test".

Works fine BUT eclipse plugin won't consider my `<testSourceDirectory>` and won't add it as  entry into my .claspath file :-( Is there a way to manipulate the eclispe plugin to add the classpath entry from the failsafe plugin? I already the following:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <additionalConfig>
                    <file>
                        <name>.classpath</name>
                        <content>
                            <![CDATA[<classpathentry kind="src" path="test/integration" output="build/compile/test-classes"/>]]>
                        </content>
                    </file>
                </additionalConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But this results in overidden .classpath file whith the above entry as single line.. :-(

Has someone a good idea to slve it?

cheers, Yellomen

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying your integration dir in `sourceIncludes` as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/specifying-source-path-inclusions-and-exclusions.html)?

Comment: No, because I want to configure different root folders for unit and integration test where "unit" or "integration" shall not be partof the package. To use `<sourceIncludes>` means to configure `<build><testSources>test</testSources></build>` which allows only one folder..